# Using Java 8 Optional for safe fetching from Map

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, option-type, nullable

I have a *nullable* `Map<String, String> myMap` in my Java 8 class.

I need to fetch a value from the map based on the following condition.

- get ***keyA***;
- if not present, get ***keyB***;
- if not present, get ***keyC***.

I understand that *Java 8*'s `Optional<T>` brings the required behavior. Is there a way to use `Optional` to elegantly get the data instead of using `containsKey` checks?

Comment: Optional is just a container for a possible value or null.  You'll still have to check the map for your desired key.  Keep it Simple Soldier.

Comment: Seems like you're looking for `Optional.ofNullable(myMap.get("keyA")).or(() -> Optional.ofNullable(myMap.get("keyB"))).or(() -> Optional.ofNullable(myMap.get("keyC")));`. But that is frowned upon as a use of optional. A better implementation could use a stream: `Stream.of("keyA", "keyB", "keyC").map(myMap::get).filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst().orElse(null);`

Answer (score 3):

Building on Alexander Ivanchenko's answer, you could get the first non-null value from the map based on a series of alternate keys:

```
public static Optional<String> getValue(Map<String, String> map,
                                        String keyA, String... keys) {
    Optional<String> result = Optional.ofNullable(map.get(keyA));
    for (String key : keys) {
        if (result.isPresent()) break;
        result = result.or(() -> Optional.ofNullable(map.get(key)));
    }
    return result;
}
```

You could use the `getOrDefault` method of map, but something like

```
map.getOrDefault("keyA", map.getOrDefault("keyB", map.get("keyC")))
```

seems overly specific and complicated, and you still have to deal with the fact that neither keyA nor keyB nor keyC might be present, so you might still get `null`, and this has the performance penalty of looking up all three values from the map no matter which is returned.

It also only works for three keys.

Comment: This also has the performance cost of getting all three values, whether or not they are used.

Comment: @LouisWasserman That's a good point.

Answer (score 1):

No.  There is no special integration of Optional with Maps.

More to the point, `Optional` does not support null values.  Assuming that by "nullable map" you mean "a map that can contain null values", **you can't possibly use `Optional`** to distinguish between "null values that are in your map" and "values that aren't in your map at all."  There is absolutely no way to use `Optional` helpfully in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an `Optional` result of retrieving the *value* corresponding to one of the given *keys* from a `Map` containing nullable values by using `Stream.ofNullable()` and `Optional.or()`.

Method [`Optional.or()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#or(java.util.function.Supplier)) expects a *supplier* of `Optional` which will be utilized only if this method was invoked on an *empty optional*.

```
public static Optional<String> getValue(Map<String, String> myMap,
                                        String keyA, String keyB, String keyC) {
    
    return Stream.ofNullable(myMap) // precaution for myMap == null
            .flatMap(map -> Stream.ofNullable(map.get(keyA)))
            .findFirst()
            .or(() -> Optional.ofNullable(myMap.get(keyB)))   // evaluated only if keyA is not present
            .or(() -> Optional.ofNullable(myMap.get(keyC)));  // evaluated only if both keyA and keyB are not present                
}
```

**Note**: the method above is meant to accommodate the ***safe fetching*** (*as the question title states*) and will return an empty `Optional` if all the given *keys* are absent or if one or more of them is mapped to a `null` *value*.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work if the `Map` has null values, though.